# Updating related objects django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, one-to-one

In my django project, I have 2 relevant models:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='e-mailaddress',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True)
    # other props not important
        
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #other props not important
```

For both creating and retrieving, it is convenient to have User as a nested object in the serializer:

```py
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = User.objects.create(**user_data)
        user.save()
        # because of reasons, an empty profile is created on initial save. This works, trust me
        d, _ = Profile.objects.update_or_create(user=user, defaults=validated_data)
        d.save()
        return d
```

HOWEVER. One action that I want to be possible as well is to update both properties of the Profile and the User at the same time. When doing this with my serializer, `serializer.is_valid()` fails as the provided email is already present in the database. This also indicates that, even if the validation passes (i.e. because of an updated email address), a new User object will be created and coupled to the Profile. So my question is:

**How do I make the validation of a serializer check if the *edit* of a nested object is valid rather than checking if a new one can be created?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find something of a workaround on my own. Using the `source` property of serializer fields, one is able to add certain properties from related objects to the serializer. In my case, I was able to add the following lines to the ProfileSerializer for the functionalities I need:

```py
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30, source='user.first_name', required=False)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=150, source='user.last_name', required=False)
    email = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, source='user.email')
```

There are more properties to `User`, but for my current requirements I don't need them and this works fine (though it would be tedious to add such a line for all properties if you need all attributes). It does require a custom implementation of both `create` and `update` functions, but I assume one would need those anyway. Personally I used:

```py
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = User.objects.create(**user_data)
        user.save()
        instance = ...
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = instance.user
        for k,v in user_data.items():
            setattr(user, k, v)
        user.save()
        ...
        return instance
```

Note: django-rest automatically groups properties with a shared source object into a nested object: `{'user': {'email': ..., 'first_name': ..., 'last_name': ...}, 'phone_number': ...}` (where `phone_number` is a profile property)

Answer (score 0):

you can update the properties of the profile and its related user by doing something similar.

```py
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    # update the profile-related fields here.
    # the other properties which you didn't mention.
    ...
    profile = instance
    # get the profile object
    ...
    instance.save()

    user = validated_data.get('user')
    # get the related user.
    # update the user properties here, like:
    user.email = 'UPDATED_EMAIL'
    user.save() # you need to save the user as well as the profile!

    return instance
```

Comment: Yes, but update is called _after_ validation, right? Part of my problem is that I don't pass the validation because the email provided in the post data (if unchanged) is invalid because of the unique constraint on email. Now that I re-read my question I see that's not too clear, sorry for that, will edit. I mainly want to know is there is some way to "tell" django-rest that the default for this (or all) relation(s) is to edit the existing one instead of creating a new one, also for validation.